# What would be the most useful BOINC project to help researchers?

Tags: math-software, experimental-mathematics

There are some distributed computing projects like BOINC? What would be the most useful BOINC project to help mathematicians or are those just waste of energy and time?

Comment: If you want to contribute to something potentially useful in near future, then math-biology-chemistry projects like Folding@Home may be the way to go. I'm personally not excited about any of the pure math distributed computing projects, but perhaps I'd feel differently if I were a number theorist.